# VScode type acquisition with global yarn packages

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, yarnpkg

I have a javascript project setup in VScode but the automatic type acquisition is not working for me. 
As far as I know, VScode checks the local and global `node_modules` folders for the `@types` directory. However, I use yarn so how would I go about telling VScode to use the correct directory?

I'm using typescript to transpire my JS down to ES5, so I have a tsconfig.json. I tried adding the path to the `global yarn dir`, but still no luck.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: So there is no local directory created by Yarn?

Comment: there is a local node_modules yes, however, I would rather not add `@types` packages to my package.json as different people use different IDEs. The other workaround, would be to manually add a local `@types` package without specifying it in package.json. And that is just tedious, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few points to this question, so let's look at how TypeScript load typings in a JavaScript project:

1. Load typings from `d.ts` files included in your project. These are loaded even if you use `@types`.
2. Check in your local `node_modules/@types`
3. If that no local `@types` are found, trigger automatic typings acquisition. This installs an `@types` package into a global cache (which is separate from your npm/yarn globals)

TypeScript does not check the npm/yarn global installation directory for `@types`.

In your case, I believe you need to:

- Install all the `@types` you need locally and include then as devDependencies in your `package.json`.
- Switch to a `jsconfig` instead of a `tsconfig` if you are only working with JavaScript. TypeScript projects do not have automatic typings acquisition enabled by default

Comment: You probably can use `typesRoot` to point to the new directory.

Comment: I thought the global cache was my npm/yarn global folder. Thanks for the info!
However, I'd rather not include my `@types` in devDependencies as I'd just be polluting the package.json with entries only I'd use as other people in my team do not use VScode. 

Changing to a jsconfig.json did the trick!
I was just using my tsconfig as settings to be used by webpack, so I just pointed webpack to jsconfig to keep those options and now VScode detects it's a JS project so type acquisition is being triggered! 
Thank you!